# OpenUDID or Mac address to choose on IOS?

Tags: ios, ios6, mac-address

Why folks are using OpenUDID and not Mac address in iOS for identification? It would be straightforward to use Mac address. All mobil devices have Mac address, it is well known, and it is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAC Address contains network device's information, which may cause security breaches, tracking, etc. Using a meaningless `OpenUDID` protects the device and its owner.

Comment: But why OpenUDID not cause security issues? OpenUDID identifies the user in the same way or am I wrong?

Comment: you cannot learn the details of the device from OpenUDID; you can learn from MAC Address.

Comment: You mean the first bytes in Mac address says something about the manufacturer of the network interface, and this cause security issues?

Comment: from the Manufacturer and the batch number, you can know which is the device.

Answer (score 1):

You should never ever use the a device specific identifier to detect a device.
Devices change owner and this would mean that you if use sells his device the new user could end up with the data of the previous owner.

Comment: We are developing with Enterprise license, this devices belongs to companies and usually they are not selling it often, but I am interested how clients are using the App.

Comment: The reason people are using OpenUDID is because Apple does not want you to use an unique users due to privacy. You can go a head and use it in an enterprise app.